# Why isn't CORS restriction applied in this code?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

I tested it on multiple browsers, and it works. Why is this possible? What am I missing here?

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data.results[0].name.first);
  }
});
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: RandomUser.me intentionally sets permissive CORS headers so it works on any site. It wouldn't be a very useful tool otherwise.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do more reading on how CORS works and how to inspect headers in browser dev tools network

Comment: CORS restrictions do apply, the fact that the site returns valid CORS headers means that CORS is **allowed**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`randomuser.me` sends the `access-control-allow-origin` header with the value `*` in every response, so the browser knows that requests from other origins are allowed:

[image: Screenshot showing the <code>access-control-allow-origin</code> response header]